# Was the death of the President of the Czech Senate a theme in the Taiwanese media?

Tags: international, taiwan, czech-republic

See also connected question: [How anticipated was visit of President of the Czech Senate in Taiwan?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/49704/how-anticipated-was-visit-of-president-of-the-czech-senate-in-taiwan)

As I am stating there, President of the Czech Senate [Jaroslav Kubera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaroslav_Kubera) was supposed to go on an official state visit to Taiwan this year.

This week (20 January 2020) he suddenly passed away.

Question:
**Was the death of the Czech President of the Senate a theme in the Taiwanese media?**
Do the common citizens of Taiwan know about that?

---

**EDIT (September 2020)**: The recent events might confuse someone, so I want to clarify: The new president of the Czech Senate ([Miloš Vystrčil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milo%C5%A1_Vystr%C4%8Dil)) fulfilled plans of the late Jaroslav Kubera and actually visited Taiwan. The question remains the same.

Comment: I sincerely doubt it, as his death does not seem related to Taiwan and in any case his position is a rather unimportant one when it comes to foreign politics, making his visit a very minor affair.

Answer (score 3):

The event of death itself might not be a theme immediately in Taiwan. However, the following event and a series of response from China make it a theme until serveral months later in 2020. In the end, lots of people and social media trigger it as a theme. The name "Kubera" somehow represents current news event in Taiwan. [REF: news release from Taiwan Government](https://english.president.gov.tw/NEWS/6035)